# How to use same tag multiple time on aws inspector resource group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I want to create a resource group in AWS inspector with terraform, that has few tags with key "Name" and different values. I can do this with AWS GUI, but I Want to do it in terraform also. If I do it like in the example below, it will just override the name..

```
resource "aws_inspector_resource_group" "bar" {
  tags = {
    Name = "Master"
    Name = "UF"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following:

```
resource "aws_inspector_resource_group" "bar" {
  tags = {
    Name = ["Master", "UF"]
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work you could just use the `aws_ec2_tag` resource:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_tag
Should do the job